# FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: path of file is not find

Tags: python, linux, windows

I am trying to open a TSV file but I am getting the error below (I am using the Windows Subsystem for Linux).

```
emmanuelle@LAPTOP-S18ARGED:/mnt/c/Users/Emmanuelle/Documents/Extraction_corpus$ python3 Feel.py
Import TreeTagger pas Ok
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "Feel.py", line 3, in <module>
    from librairies_extraction import *
  File "/mnt/c/Users/Emmanuelle/Documents/Extraction_corpus/librairies_extraction.py", line 33, in <module>
    file = open(os.path.join(path, l + '.tsv'), 'r', encoding='utf-8')
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/mnt/c/Users/Emmanuelle/Documents/Extraction_corpus/data/1924_freins.tsv'
```

```
file_path = '/mnt/c/Users/Emmanuelle/Documents/Extraction_corpus'
l = '1924_freins'
d = 'data'
path = os.path.join(file_path, d)

file = open(os.path.join(path, l + '.tsv'), 'r', encoding='utf-8')
l_1 = [line.rstrip() for line in file]


csv_df = pd.DataFrame({'Contenu':l_1})
```

Comment: Are you using Ubuntu app of microsoft store?

Comment: @Toby Yes indeed

Comment: try `mnt/c/Users` to `./../../c/Users` assume that you are in home directory

Comment: @Toby still not working!! I am in the howe directory : 
/mnt/c/Users/Emmanuelle/Documents/Extraction_corpus

Comment: I am not sure how many time we should use `../` to go from `home` to `mnt`, please check the directory, I am not using that for a long time. And I am wrong on the example above, it should be `./../../mnt/c/Users/`

Comment: @Toby still the same errors

Comment: ah, I saw that you run `python3 Feel.py` in the same directory with `ibrairies_extraction.py` so try to change `file_path = ''` then try again